# Change toggle behavior of Input Source Keyboard Shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

I've recently switched from Ubuntu 16.04 o 18.04, and there's one thing that bugs me.

The problem I have is the behavior of keyboard layout toggling in 18.04. I have 3 keyboard layouts, say *[X,Y,Z]* that I toggle in-between with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

In Ubuntu 16.04, clicking <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> with pause in-between changed the layout from X -> Y, Y -> Z, Z -> X. So just to the next layout from the list *[X,Y,Z]*.

In Ubuntu 18.04 , clicking <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> would change the layout to *the most recent layout*. So if I'm using layout *X* and changes to *Y* by tapping  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, next time I try to change layout the list would look something like *[Y,X,Z]*, so if I would like to change to *Z* I have to double tap instead of once.

So my question is, how can I change the layout toggling behavior in 18.04 to match the Ubuntu 16.04 one?

I guess this difference is because of GNOME in 18.04, but I can't find a similar question/answer. I'm new here so I might just have missed something obvious, but help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello @pomsky thank you for the swift reply! "Static ordering" is the keyword I apparently missed while looking for answers. I guess the answer solves my problem, so I'll close the question. It is mildy annoying that I have to change my toggle shortcut to Alt+Shift, but I guess I'll have to get used to it. Thanks!